# Unused red fan wire

Tags: electrical

We replaced a fan that required the three wires, white, black and red with one that is controlled by a remote and only uses the white and black wires.  My question…since there’s a light switch that used to control the light can I use the red wire and switch to control 4 can (pot) LED lights?  Thanks for the information.

Comment: Be careful not to put the can lights too close to the fan. The pitfall is moving as shadows when both fan and lights are on.

Comment: Yes there is a switch to it.  How do I wire the cans?  The ones I have, have the white, black and ground...how do I hook just one wire?

Comment: If you want more advice about making sure you haven't double-stuffed the box, turn the power off at the panel and post a photo of the innards of the box in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll run a /2 cable to the fan-box from the can-lights and connect bare to the rest of the bares, white to the rest of the whites, and black on the new cable to the existing red wire -- wire-nuts or Wagos are available at any big-box or hardware store.  Just watch your box fill and make sure you aren't overstuffing the junction box -- you may need a round/octagon volume marked mud ring to add a few extra cubic inches with the additional cable/clamp installed.

And yes, don't put the can lights where the fan blades can block them, otherwise you'll get annoying shadows when both are on.

Answer (score 0):

If the light can handle 120V, sure. Be aware that the red wire is usually used with a switch.